# How can I prevent wrong count on database query and update?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, concurrency, signalr

the problem I'm facing is:

I have a **MVC web app** using signalr, it works perfectly fine but I still have a problem when **a few users** (tested it with 15 users) **go to the site at the same exact time**. Sometimes a **counter** reflects the actual number, sometimes it doesn't.

What I have is a int variable in a class, and when a new user makes a request for the /play page the /display page gets it's counter incremented using signalr.

Just to try to make users update this variable at different times I added a

`Thread.Sleep(random);`

before incrementing the counter.

Is there a better way to handle concurrency on this kind of scenario?

Would appreciate an example because I've tried lot's of things and I'm on the clock.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you defining the "int variable"?

Comment: public static int userCount = 0;

I'm refreshing it on the get method of the /play page, after some validations.

Comment: Apply the Singleton pattern to the class.

Comment: You should provide the code used to broadcast the counter and the code that triggers that broadcast so we can check if anything is wrong

Comment: Thread.Sleep(random); is never the answer for threading (or for the server). If you share the variable and want to increment it atomically use Interlocked.Increment

Comment: Exactly where are you declaring the int for the counter? Is it is your Hub class? The other comments are all applicable.

Comment: I don't know about singleton here, the counter is declared in the controller, as it should increment when a new request is made, not sure if this is OK.

In the ActionResult Play() I increment the counter and after that I broadcast the user counter.

I added the Interlocked.Increment and I'm gonna test it now. Hope this works, this must be working for monday morning :( Thanks for all your help!!!!

Comment: Try a shared variable with Interlocked.Increment and let us know the result.

Comment: Used and tested the interlock approach, worked fine for 10-15 people but didn't work so fine with a group of 60, counter was not reflecting the actual 60.